# How to search someone else’s old tweets?

Tags: twitter

I have been trying to search few users’ old tweets, old tweets as 6K back but after trying all websites, I can just track 3200 tweets not more. Anyone who can help me how to find them?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter limits the amount of tweets that can be served through the API. From the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline):

> (...)
>   The timeline returned is the equivalent of the one seen when you view
>   a user's profile on twitter.com.
>
> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user's most recent
>   statuses. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in
>   this total (...)

Tweets that are older still exist, but can only be fetched by [a specific ID](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid)

So, to answer your question: I'm afraid it is not possible to fetch 6k tweets from one user. At least not with the Twitter API that's available to the public.